# Is there an Arabic translation of the Book of Mormon?

Tags: lds, book-of-mormon, translation

I know that the Book of Mormon is not officially printed in Hebrew, but is it officially printed in Arabic?

I know that the LDS church does not proselyte in any shape or form in the Middle East (except for parts of Turkey, I think?), but do they have the Book of Mormon translated in Arabic for the many Muslims that live outside the Middle East? I also know that proselyting to Muslims, regardless of their location, is a sensitive issue, but in special circumstances is still done. Anyway, the main question is in regards to an Arabic translation of the Book of Mormon.

Do you know where one can obtain a copy?

Comment: According to this page ( https://www.lds.org/liahona/1997/06/in-his-own-language?lang=eng&_r=1 ) a translation into "Arabic" was made and/or published in 1986. Also, there is a story floating around about some guy named Sami Hanna who tried translating tBoM into Arabic and was converted as a result; although apparently he deconverted sometime later ( http://www.greaterthings.com/Topical/BofM_Arabic.htm ). It's not clear whether this translation was ever completed or published. Also, keep in mind that "Arabic" is actually a large family of languages, not a single language.

Comment: http://ldsmediatalk.com/translations-of-the-book-of-mormon/ This article lists all of the current translations of the Book of Mormon.

Comment: The Book of Mormon is indeed available in Hebrew.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, the Book of Mormon is translated into Arabic (كتاب مورمون), as well as the Doctrine and Covenants and Pearl of Great Price. A scanned PDF of the Arabic Book of Mormon can be found [here](https://www.lds.org/bc/content/shared/content/arabic/pdf/language-materials/34406_ara.pdf), and a physical copy can be purchased from [Store.LDS.org](https://store.lds.org/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/Product3_715839595_10557_3074457345616706302_-1__197030). A list of other LDS materials in Arabic can be found on [LDS.org](https://www.lds.org/languages/ara?lang=eng&clang=ara).

The full Book of Mormon is currently available in 88 languages, including other Middle-Eastern languages like Persian (Farsi) and Turkish. A full list, with links, is available here:
http://scripturetools.net/availability